# Create Table Using Plain SQL?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to use Slick 3's Plain Sql `sql` to create a table:

```
scala> import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

scala> sql""" CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR` (`BIPPY` varchar(32) NOT NULL) """
res0: slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder = SQLActionBuilder(Vector( CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR` (`BIPPY` varchar(32) NOT NULL) ),<function2>)
```

I attempted in vain via `as[...]` to get it to compile.

```
scala> res0.as[Nothing]
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[Nothing]
       res0.as[Nothing]
              ^

scala> res0.as[Unit]
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[Unit]
       res0.as[Unit]
              ^
```

How can I fix the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is: use `sql` for anything that returns a result set, and `sqlu` for anything else.

So, you've got it: use `sqlu`. However, there is a variation to know about...

**asUpdate**

In addition to `as[T]`, the `sql` interpolator gives you an `asUpdate` method:

```
scala> sql"""create table foo(x int) """.asUpdate
res1: slick.profile.SqlStreamingAction[Vector[Int],Int,slick.dbio.Effect]#ResultAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect] = slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction@647bf3c3
```

To run that you'd `db.run(res1)`, which would give you output like this:

```
DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: create table foo(x int)
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - 0 rows affected
res2: Int = 0
```

...which also gives you the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. Could you please let me know how you enabled the DEBUG output?

Comment: Sure - you need a logging backend (e.g., log4j, or logback) and then enable the logging in a configuration file.  For example we use logback in [this build.sbt](https://github.com/underscoreio/essential-slick-code/blob/3.0/chapter-01/build.sbt#L22) and configure it in src/main/resources/[logback.xml](https://github.com/underscoreio/essential-slick-code/blob/3.0/chapter-01/src/main/resources/logback.xml).  Change `slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement` from "INFO" to "DEBUG" and you'll get output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqlu` worked:

```
scala> import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

scala> val action: DBIO[Int] = sqlu""" CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (BIPPY 
                                          varchar(32) NOT NULL) """
action: slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api.DBIO[Int] = slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction@47b8399e
```

Credit - [Essential Slick](http://underscore.io/training/courses/essential-slick/)